# How to add image in comment section?

Tags: discussion, comments, meta

If I look at the help under comment section it mentioned ctrl+i will let me insert an image. It does not work for me.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are too diligent :) and so read too much of the formatting help.  It starts with

> Comments support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few shorthand links are available.

Under this section, there is a hint: the above section is quoted for convenience from the full editing help, below. One gets this part on the top when coming from the comment help.

Images are for posts in any case, not for comments.  At the same time, interestingly enough, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>, I don't get the image snippet but the italic one.

There is a followup post now, by [AndriyM](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6965/andriy-m): [Wrong shortcut key information in Help Center](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2743/6219)

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+I doesn't bring the image insert box for me either. I think that's because the shortcut key for that action is actually Ctrl+G (but it won't work in a comment box).