# Wrong shortcut key information in Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed

The [Markdown help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page of the Help Center contains a misleading piece of information about a shortcut key. It says in the [Images](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images) section:

> You can also press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to insert an image.

However, in [Italics and Bold](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help#italics-bold) it mentions the same combination:

> You can also select text and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to toggle italics or bold respectively.

It doesn't make much sense to overload a single key combination with two distinct operations, and indeed it only works for toggling italics for me, not for inserting an image. And I believe that is how it is meant to work, because the correct combination for inserting an image is actually <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, which can be found in the tooltip appearing when you hover over the *Image* toolbar button:

[image: Editor textbox toolbar]

I believe this should be reflected in the Help Center. Specifically, the above mentioned line from the Images section of the Markdown help page should actually read:

> You can also press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to insert an image.

replacing "<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>" with "<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>".

Comment: I second your proposal.

Comment: @hot2use And I third it! #internationalbadjokeday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! A fix has been pushed and will be live with our next production build!

Comment: Excellent, thanks!